# How to get emulated storage path on Android 6?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I want to get the emulated storage path. `System.getenv("EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET")` works on previous versions i.e Android 5 and below but returns null on Android 6. I searched on google but couldn't find anything. How can I get the emulated storage path on Android 6. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What do you consider an "emulated storage path" to be, exactly?

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the reply, I consider it to be the internal storage if I am not wrong. The path for this is usually /storage/emulated/0/ (0 stands for the user).

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be referring to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), which on some versions of Android will be located at `/storage/emulated/0/`. The proper way to obtain the root of external storage, on *all* versions of Android, is by means of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

If you find yourself using environment variables in an Android app, you are doing it wrong.